# Professional Website Builder

Tags: language-agnostic

I have been developing in ASP.NET and c#, actionscript flash/flex cs3, and the iPhone.  I have a little all around knowledge of everything including html, css, and jQuery.

Usually I write applications, and now I want to build a commercial website with videos and testimonials and automailing.  I recently bought a MacBook Pro and I love the ease of use for building simple personal websites.  I want something similar but more powerful.  I have found Dreamweaver a little difficult on the design side ( I have not tried CS4 yet).

I do not want to use joomla or drupal because they are to difficult for me to customize.

What website builder do you think is easiest and best to build professional websites and what productivity/design features do you like best about it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Wny not just ask "which is the simplest website builder for mac? :)

Comment: If you don't need WYSIWYG, [http://panic.com/coda](Coda) is a very good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET, you may want to consider [Sitefinity CMS](http://www.sitefinity.com). If you know your way around Visual Studio, you can create some pretty awesome sites with content management system functionality built in. The vendor offers a free community edition too. There are several built in templates, or you can build your own with a little use of Master pages and Photoshop.

An no the above is not a shameless plug :) I have used the product for about 4 years for many sites.

You can create any custom functionality you want for the site via UserControls or more advanced Modules.

I've used Dreamweaver for about 10 years and I wouldn't really recommend it unless you're working on static sites.

Comment: He said he *just bought* a mac ;)

Comment: Lol wow speed-reading is overrated.. :)

Comment: I've heard rumors about Windows running on Macs now, too ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [uCoz](http://www.ucoz.com) for about 3 years, and I find it as the most developed free website builder to create websites, when you want to use  html, css, and jQuery. This after using both other CMS systems like Joomla, Drupal and Free Website builders like Webs and Weebly.          It's simple to customize, being almost open source (although linked to the hosting), but yet, it's powered by a CMS with 22 Modules.

It gives a lot of flexibility, its  250+ templates can be customized (using CSS/HTML). You can also use PHP (although some functions are limited).